# Cannot receive data from factory in controller (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

Why second `console.log` gives me undefined when first one prints actual data? How to assign data received in promise to any variable to be able to use it without promise?

```
angular.module('dopasujApp')
    .controller('productLoader', [ '$scope','getProducts',
        function ($scope,getProducts) {
            $scope.recived = {};
            console.log($scope.list);
            function getter() {
                return getProducts(1, 150, 20, 'ASC', 'PRODUCT_ID', 'a').then(function (recived) {
                        $scope.recived = recived;
                        console.log($scope.recived);
                    }
                );
            }

            getter();
            console.log($scope.recived);
        }
]);
```

Here is my factory code:

```
angular.module('dopasujApp').factory('getProducts', ['$http', function ($http) {
 return function(fit = 1, limit = 150, vendor = 20, sort = 'ASC', orderBy = 'PRODUCT_ID', search='a', size=[], filters={}, attribs=[]) {
     var getProduct = {}, recived = {}, APIurl;
     getProduct.data={};
     getProduct.data.sort=sort;
     getProduct.data.orderBy=orderBy;
     getProduct.data.search=search;
     getProduct.data.filters=filters;
     getProduct.data.filters.ATTRIBS=attribs;
     getProduct.data.filters.SIZE=size;
     recived.list= [];
     recived.count = 0;
     recived.filters = {};
     APIurl = "*******?action=getListing&fit="+fit+"&limit="+limit+"&vendor="+vendor;
     var request = $http({
         method: "POST",
         url: APIurl,
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
         data: {
            data:  getProduct.data
         }
     });

     var values = request.then(function (response){
         return {
             list: response.data.QUERY,
             count: response.data.COUNT,
             filters: response.data.FILTERS
         };
     });
     return values;
 }
 }]);
```

Comment: Can you share your service code?

Comment: Sure, ill edit question.

Answer (score 3):

Because your getProducts is a promise, and even tough your second console.log is after your getter();, the console.log is executed before your promise is resolved, thats why its undefined.

Comment: to add to this... `getter().then(function() { console.log($scope.recived);})` would be proper way to do second log

Comment: Ok, but how to get actual data? I mean, how to assign actual received data to `$scope.recived` or any other variable to able to use it without promise?

Comment: You are already assigning it, arent you? With $scope.recived = recived; inside the promise?

Comment: Yeah the promise waits for the data, and the console.log runs immediately. You need to wait for the getter... ie @charlietfl getter().then() is the way to go.

Comment: So it prints undefined not because I did it wrong, but because it not done yet when im trying to print it? Eh, now i get it... So actually using promise in factory gives me nothing, right?